# Android Animated radial fade

Tags: android, animation, gradient, fade, radial-gradients

I'm trying to animate an image so that it fades to white using a radial gradient growing from out to in. E.g a radial gradient with the centre as transparent and edges white, then collapsing inwards until the whole image is white.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is to overlay an View on top of my ImageView. I've set the View's background as an drawablexml file I've put into my drawable folder containing a simple white-to-transparent gradient:

```
"radialgrad.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gradientRadius="1000dp"
        android:type="radial"
        />
</shape>
```

This is where it's used:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivMain"
        android:src="@drawable/imagetohide"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/vRadial"
    android:background="@drawable/radialgrad"/>
</RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. In my activity, I'm using findViewById to get the View containing the gradient, but how do I change it's background's attribute, gradientRadius? I'm trying to use:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(vRadial, "gradientRadius", 1000, 0);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
                anim.start();
```

But it doesn't work and doesn't seem right. The attribute belongs to vRadial's background, not vRadial itself.

Any alternate suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a gradient property as second parameter of `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat()`.

ObjectAnimator class is designed instead to animate `View` properties, as for instance `scaleX`, `translationX`, etc.

You should use 'alpha' attribute, applied on ImageView

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgView, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see about using alpha. However, this would animate the transparency of the entire radial gradient/image view. I'm looking to create this effect:

![Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4jlu.png)

Comment: Ok, so it could be useful override onDraw() method, and specify the gradient radius frame by frame. In other words increasing the gradient radius and then call invalidate().